# c++ reading multiple lines from a file into a class

Tags: c++, string, io, delimiter

I have the following text file layout:

> Person:Eugene Sandoval ;26;Male
>   Reporter
>   Artist
>   Person:Johanna Gibbs;34;Female
>   Circus worker
>   Film producer
>   Bank clerk

The first line has some information about the person and the next lines are his or hers previous jobs.

This is the class I made:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person
{
public:
  Person() {};
  ~Person() {};

  std::string name;
  std::string age;
  std::string gender;

  std::vector<std::string> previousJobs;

  friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Person& p)
  {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::getline(iss, p.name, ';');
    std::getline(iss, p.age, ';');
    std::getline(iss, p.gender, ';');

    return is;
  }
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
     std::vector<Person> people;
     std::ifstream input_file("Resources/data.txt");

     Person p

     while (input_file >> p)
     {
        people.push_back(p);
     }

     getchar();
     return 0;
}
```

So far I am succesfull reading the first line into the object. But I am struggling with reading the previous jobs into the vector.

Comment: As it stands now, `name` will include the `"person:"` part. After reading a line from the stream you should first check for this `"person:"` string, retrieve `name`, `age` and `gender` upon a match and then keep reading lines from the stream to put in the vector until you hit another line containing `"person:"`.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file struct".  There are already a plethora of questions and examples of **read**ing from a text **file** into a **struct**.

Answer (score 0):

After the successful reading the first line of your file and parsing it using the `istringstream`, you can do the same with other lines. If you are sure that a single file contains information about one person, then you might freely use:

```
while (![your_file].eof())
{
  previousJobs.push_back(getline(is,line));
}
```